# Is it ethical to share information that could get a competitive colleague fired?

Tags: colleagues, ethics

I have information that could get a competitive colleague fired. If I share it, I would have to do it anonymously. This colleague has done some very shady things to me in the past.

I'm feeling uneasy about sharing this information. Is it ethical to share this information?

Comment: Do you want to share the info just to get the competitor fired, or would that simply be an additional benefit to having that information out in the open?

Comment: What does 'competitor' mean?  A co-worker?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek yes. I work in a very competitive sales environment and I have proof that one of my competitors is working for two companies at one time.

Comment: I would like for her to get fired. As awful as that is for me to admit. I also know her personally and she is not a nice human being and has hurt people I know. She is greedy (obviously) and believes she is superior.

Comment: Is what she is doing hurting your company, or potentially will hurt it?

Comment: Also, if it comes out some other way, and it's known that you already knew, would that hurt or help you?

Comment: What she is doing does not hurt my company however, she has a strong presence in my territory. She is a bully and she  dominates the territory. Everytime I try to win a new account she is the one I am up against. She is a fraud.

Comment: **...fraud***: Is she cheating, or just better than you?

Comment: @Devnull She is not cheating me. Is she better than me? Maybe.

Comment: Full disclosure. She was sleeping with my old boss and he let me go because she wanted to take over my territory.

Comment: @Mary :0 so now on this new job you crossed paths again with her? Is your "proof" the fact she is having an affair? If so, consider including that on your post as it is *highly* relevant

Comment: No, the proof does not include her having an affair. That would be a low blow for sure. This is strictly the fact that I have proof she is working two jobs that are in direct competition with her job. I know it is for selfish reasons that I would like to see her implode and it would be nice to have her out of my territory but the proof is strictly about a professional misstep.

Comment: Your first problem is that you think of your coworkers as competitors.

Comment: @Flater When I posted that comment the question actually said "competitor".

Comment: This is currently very unclear. What I know for certain: You had a job, she was sleeping with your boss from that job, the boss then let you go. What I don't know: was she a colleague in that job (or was she "recruited" to replace you), is she a colleague now, or is she working for one or more of your business's competitors?

Answer (score 10):

> What should I do? Just let Karma take over? Or share the info?

Based on your comments, if this is something that *does not hurt the company*, and also *your job does not include* exposing colleagues or hunting these proofs I'd say you **don't do it and focus on your job instead**.

Sure, you can expose her and gain some extra space on your "territory". But that is something you have to decide by yourself.

Just be careful that this "proof" is not a setup by someone (perhaps this person?) with the hopes that *you* fall for it and end up watered.

I think you would have better chances if you focus on improving your job skills and techniques, instead of eliminating the competitors.

Comment: In the comments, OP mentioned `This is strictly the fact that I have proof she is working two jobs that are in direct competition with her job.` This is actually damaging to the company, thus nullifying your argument for suggesting OP to not speak up about it.

Comment: My argument is not only based on that. Besides, yours assumes it's OPs job to play police. Furthermore, op asked on the ethics and "kharmic" aspects of doing so. Op also clarified before that this does not damage the company according to their pov, if you read *all* comments: *"what she is doing does not hurt the company, she has..."*

Answer (score 5):

> What should I do?

There is nothing wrong with taking out competition, the ethical side and karma is your personal choice.

Doing it anonymously seems a bit shady, but if you have to for your own protection there is nothing intrinsically wrong with that either.

Comment: Thanks. I want to remain anonymous because this person is CRAZY and I am fearful of her.

Comment: However, I also feel as if I should let karma do its work on her. I am afraid I will have bad karma if I do this to her. But maybe the universe was trying to help me by having this "Proof" land in my lap.

Comment: @Mary well, we are deviating from the workplace territory into more philosophical topics, but perhaps the real test the universe sent you is to see how you react when given the chance to "destroy" someone...

Comment: @DarkCygnus. Yes. THANK YOU! You just answered my soul's question. I know this is not right. I need to put my head down and work and forget about this nonsense. The universe will manage this as it is suppose to be handled. Thank you. You have inspired me. You must be much more evolved and enlightened than me. Your answer gave me a resounding YES in my heart. Thats it my friend. That is my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary I am really glad I could help you. Not sure if I am much more evolved or something, but I try my best to navigate the workplace (and this life) the best I can. Really glad I could inspire you :D good luck with that ;)

Comment: @DarkCygnus, I don't know if you believe in this kind of stuff but I honestly think you were a conduit from my guardian angels. Thank you.

Comment: @Mary (I know comments are not for this but, nothing that can't be pruned) Well, as I've disclosed elsewhere, my real name is Miguel (Michael)... so ;) furthermore, to give you even more chills, I had a *really* spiritual and lucid dream last night. I finally saw my mother (RIP) in it since she passed away, and other really personal and spiritual things. Today I woke up renewed, like I shed some skin that was weighting me down since some time now... you just gotta love how "random strangers" on the internet, on this SE platform, can have this sort of coincidences. Have a wonderful day Mary

Comment: I drank far too much whiskey last night and had some awesome insights into life the universe and everything,.... but can't remember them.

Answer (score 5):

> If I share the proof I have I would share it anonymously.
>
> But, in my heart I am feeling uneasy about sharing this information.

The fact that you aren't willing to do this in the open and in your heart feel uneasy, and you wrote that you know in your heart "this is not right" - tells me that you realize this will be unethical.

Comment: Or it really is the ethical thing to do and Mary is a good person, so Mary is reluctant to do something that hurts another and helps herself, for fear of letting personal bias lead her into something wrong.  Either explanation fits the facts.

Answer (score 3):

> This is strictly the fact that I have proof she is working two jobs that are in direct competition with her job.

So AFAIU, she is working two jobs additional jobs when, by contract and/or expectation of HR she should be only doing none without registering with HR. *Potentially she did this without anybody knowing, so judging may is none of your business*. But lets assume she did not, then the following applies:

I do not understand how this "does not hurt the company". It is central to the expectations of an employer where you have an employment that you are supposed not to work side jobs in secret. Even if it does not hurt the company currently every day in a measurable way, it still has the potential to do so, and, depending on her behavior in the other jobs actually already is (without you knowing). This person would be self-centered and maybe lying to cover up the fact that she works multiple jobs. Such behavior undermines everything which you need in a team. Besides she have proven one time (together with you old boss) that she does not hesitate to act against the company interest.

As i wrote before, you don't know what HR knows or not. I don't know the country you are in, so i don't know their viewpoint and the laws on it. You could do one of the following:

- The most straightforward way would be when you find a real problem. E.g. orders being processed late or constant difficulty in arranging a meeting since she has strong time restrictions from her other jobs. If that is the case, go to you boss (assuming she is not sleeping with him again) and state this specific thing. If he says something like "I dont understand why colleague doesn't have time", consider it an invitation to speak out.
- In Germany: go to the working council  and ask for advice (without telling the colleagues name)
- Go to HR or you boss, talk to them, first asking **without telling the colleagues name** if they would like to be informed in such a situation. "It came to my attention that a colleague is potentially working additional jobs and i wonder if I can or should tell you more specific about this suspicion confidentially" - never state it as  a fact, it is not your task to establish if it is a fact.

I personally see this less as an ethical problem (she exhibited behaviors which hurt companies in the long run), but more one where you could get burned if it turns out that she registered the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps karma has chosen *you* to be the instrument by which this vicious and unethical person gets what she deserves.

It is not "ethical" to ignore unethical behavior. An unethical person, left unchecked, will go on to cause harm to people that you don't even know about yet. On behalf of those innocents, as well as for yourself, you should speak up.